# Is there an alignment in the separation of ancient temples / complexes?

Tags: geography

British writer [Graham Hancock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_Hancock) has made some claims about the location of Easter Island, Giza, and Angkor Wat.

> Because the distance between the Great Pyramid and Angkor is very nearly 20% of the circumference, they are very nearly 72° apart, along the circle. Because the distance from the Great Pyramid to Easter Island is very nearly 40% of the circumference, and the distance from Angkor to Easter Island is very nearly 40% of the circumference, the Great Pyramid and Angkor are both very nearly 144° away from Easter Island, along the circle.

Is this true?

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) To avoid use tackling strawman arguments, we [expect references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. I went to add such an example of the claim, and it did not match your description. Please either show that he said they were "exactly" 72° apart, or update the question based on what he actually claims.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search gives

Angkor wat: 13.4125° N, 103.8670° E

Great pyramid of Giza: 29.9792° N, 31.1342° E

So they differ in longitude by 72.73°

Easter island is at 27.1127° S, 109.3497° W

Which is 140.4° West of Giza.

So, not that close to the supposed exact values.

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it. It is worth adding that at the latitudes of Easter Island and Giza, a single degree of longitude is nearly 100km long, which makes the approximation not very close.

Comment: Note that this answer tackles a strawman, set up in the original version of the question.

Comment: This answer appears to be missing references.  Presumably the longitudes/latitudes are fairly uncontroversial, so Wikipedia links should suffice.  WolframAlpha's great for linking calculations, if you care to get fancy.